# R Sort one column ascending, all others descending (based on column order)

Tags: r, sorting, multiple-columns

I have an ordered table, similar to as follows:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"A   B   C   Size
1   0   0   1
0   1   1   2
0   0   1   1
1   1   0   2
0   1   0   1",
header = TRUE)
```

In reality there will be many more columns, but this is fine for a solution.

I wish to sort this table first by SIZE (Ascending), then by *each other* column in priority sequence (Descending) - i.e. by column A first, then B, then C, etc.

The problem is that I will not know the column names in advance so cannot name them, but need in effect "all columns except SIZE".

End result should be:

```
A B C Size
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
1 1 0 2
0 1 1 2
```

I've seen examples of sorting by two columns, but I just can't find the correct syntax to sort by 'all other columns sequentially'.

Many thanks

Comment: Are all those columns numeric or integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `arrange` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(df, Size, desc(A), desc(B), desc(C))
```

---

For more number of columns, `arrange_` can be used

```
cols <-  paste0("desc(", names(df)[1:3], ")")
arrange_(df, .dots = c("Size", cols))
```

Answer (score 12):

With the names use `order` like this.  No packages are used.

```
o <- with(df, order(Size, -A, -B, -C))
df[o, ]
```

This gives:

```
  A B C Size
1 1 0 0    1
5 0 1 0    1
3 0 0 1    1
4 1 1 0    2
2 0 1 1    2
```

or without the names just use column numbers:

```
o <- order(df[[4]], -df[[1]], -df[[2]], -df[[3]])
```

or

```
k <- 4
o <- do.call("order", data.frame(df[[k]], -df[-k]))
```

If `Size` is always the last column use `k <- ncol(df)` instead or if it is not necessarily last but always called Size then use `k <- match("Size", names(df))` instead.

**Note:** Although not needed in the example shown in the question if the columns were not numeric then one could not negate them so a more general solution would be to replace the first line above with the following where `xtfrm` is an R function which converts objects to numeric such that the result sorts in the order expected.

```
o <- with(df, order(Size, -xtfrm(A), -xtfrm(B), -xtfrm(C)))
```

Comment: Columns are numeric, but I don't want to name them explicitly as they may differ in each execution.

Comment: See addition at the end just before the Note.